# Class object in PDO not working with SQL Update

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem. I don't know why the function updateProduct in the class Product is not working. I did use the updateProduct function to delete one product in the 'products' table, but it didn't work. Can someone explain it to me? Thank you

Ps: I am sure that in my 'products' table, there is a product with the productID is 10, but when I did run the updateProduct, the name of the product with the productID is 10 is not updated

db.php

```
    <?php
class report_error{
    function http_error($message) 
    {
        header("Content-type: text/plain");
        die($message);
    }
}
    
class connection_db{
    private $hostname = "localhost";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $dbname = "name";
    public $conn = NULL;
    public function connection(){
        try 
        {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->hostname;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password);
            if($this->conn != null){echo "sucessfully connected";}
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            $error_out = new report_error();
            $error_out->http_error("500 Internal Server Error\n\n"."There was a SQL error:\n\n" . $e->getMessage());
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }
}

?>
```

product.php

```
    <?php
class Product{
    private $categoryID;
    private $ProductCode;
    private $ProductName;
    private $listPrice;
    public function updateProduct($prodID, $prodName, $conn){
        $query='Update products Set productName=:productName Where productID=:productID';
        $q=$conn->prepare($query);
        $q->bindValue(':productName',$prodName);
        $q->bindValue(':productID',$prodID);
        $q->execute();
    }
}

?>
```

test_function.php

```
    <?php
require 'db.php';
require 'product.php';
$db = new connection_db();
$conn = $db->connection();

$prod=new Product();

//updateProduct
$prod->updateProduct(10, 'Ludwig 4-pieces Drum Set with Cymbals', $conn);
?>
```

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: Use bindParam instead of bindValue https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php